# How to make git clone install cli tool?

Tags: terminal, git, npm

I am creating a cli tool in nodejs, that i want people to be able to run like this:

```
git clone mytool.git
mytool -arg1
```

Is it possible, or there needs to be a step in between. What would it be.

Comment: Have you explored packaging your software and using standard package management tools, such as `rpm` or `deb`?

Comment: using rpm or deb is the real solution but there's no reason cloning a git repo and running the scripts/executables it brings down won't work. It would just be a clunky and unfamiliar way for people to get your software.

Answer (score 1):

Since `git clone` will create a new directory, you will need to either `cd` to that directory or include it in the command path as `mytool/mytool -arg1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little script that you can give to your friends who want to use your program:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
git clone mytool.git
cd yourproject
./mytool -arg1
```